# Проверка условия на false

Tags: javascript, условия

Как корректно проверить если элемент не содержит например класс `active`?
Как правильнее делать?

```
1) if (this.classList.contains('active') === false) { выполнить код ...}
2) if (this.classList.contains('active') == false) { выполнить код ...}
3) if (!this.classList.contains('active')) { выполнить код ...}
```

Comment: `if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {}` - я би сделал так

Comment: В данном конкретном случае все три варианта абсолютно верны. Какой использовать - зависит от codeStyle в вашем проекте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все три варианта "правильные" и будут работать. Плюсом я бы предложил к рассмотрению следующую конструкцию:

```
{
    if (this.classList.contains('active')) return false;
    /* ваш код */
}
```